# jQuery preventDefault stopping serialize and subsequent ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization, submit

I have a php page that has multiple forms on it, and I want the jquery to hide each form after submit is clicked (without refreshing the page).  The id's of the forms are dynamically generated and unique each time the php page is created.

If I don't use `preventDefault`, then the script below submits the data, but it refreshes the page (which I don't want).  If I use `preventDefault`, the form still submits, but with no data (the `serialize` does not appear to work).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".connection").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var element = $(this);
        var connectid = element.attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/beta/membersarea.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#connected_" + connectid).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});​   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` in your code is the submit button, not the form...   `this` in jQuery handlers is the DOM element that the handler is attached to.

change from this:

```
$(".connection").click
```

To this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $element = $(this);
        var data = $element.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/beta/membersarea.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                $element.hide();
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: You'll also have to change your success function to be just `element.hide();` and you can probably get rid of `var connectid = element.attr("id");`

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault is to prevent the default action which is the normal form submit in this case. I guess your problem is you are not serializing the right element (form). try this

`$(this)` means the current item. When you access $(this) in a submit button click, it refers to the submit button element in the form. Not the form which is holding the submit button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".connection").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $("form").serialize();
        var element = $(this);
        var connectid = element.attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/beta/membersarea.php",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: data,
                success: function(data)
                {
                $("#connected_"+connectid).hide();
                }
              });
      });    
});
```

Assuming `connection` is the class name of your button for submit.

Comment: "I have a php page that has **multiple** forms on it" - how is `.serialize()` going to act when called on a jQuery object containing more than one form?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: In that case, probably i would serialize the purticular div which has the step. Or If it is 1/2 values i have to send, i will read manually and send as json.